# Similarity between sum of probabilities and Grassman formula

Tags: proof-explanation

I don't know if this has been covered before, or if there's even anything to say about this.

On the first hand, given to events $A,B$ with probability $P(A),P(B)$, we can prove from the axioms of probability that (for events not necessarily disjoint) the probability of $A\cup B$ is

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).$$

On the other, we have that given two subspaces $F,G$ of a finite-dimensional vector space $E$, we can prove what's known as Grassman's formula, which can be written as

$$\text{dim}(F+G)=\text{dim}(F)+\text{dim}(G)-\text{dim}(F\cap G).$$

This two formulae look incredibly similar, but even after proving both I don't understand how is it that they look so similar. Is there any argument, relation, bijection or analogy that makes this intuitive?

Comment: This is called the inclusion exclusion principle. You might want to look here also : https://mathoverflow.net/q/17740/41873